# Matching specific characters individually except in specific expression

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

Let's say I have a string: 
`cat_dog_ !mouse= <name="Jake_Russell!"> gog+cat`

I want to match specific symbols `_!=+`, but not in `<name="Jake_Russell!">` that part of this regex `<name=\".+\">`. So result should be `__!=+`

I've tried lookAhead: 
`(?!<name=\".+\">)([_!=+])` 
but as a result, it matches symbols in `<name="Jack_Russell!">` too.

Comment: Is another way of expressing the requirement *match a list of special characters, except when they are between quotes*?

Comment: @Bohemian the requirement is to match a list of special characters. But everywhere except this specific pattern expression: <name=\".+\">. Not just between quotes. Symbol `=` in  `<name="...` shouldn't be matched too

Comment: Unrelated: The dog breed is [Jack Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Russell_Terrier), not Jake Russel

Comment: I don't think you can do it because you'd need a variable length look behind, which are not supported. Would not matching within quotes and not matching after `<name=` work for you?

Comment: @Bohemian, related to unrelated: as shown at your link, the dog breed is Jack Russell Terrier. Note two "l"'s in "Russell" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (great dogs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try capturing groups, capture part `<name=\".+\">` into 1 ignored group, and another group for matched specific symbols.

Regex patten: `(?<ignored_group><name=".+">)|(?<matched_group>[_!=+])`

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PhMUIV/1)

Comment: Thanks! A named group is a suitable option in my case

Answer (score 2):

You can rule out what you don't want, and then capture when you want using an alternation and a capture group:

```
<name="[^"]*">|([_!=+])
```

**Explanation**

- `<name=` Match literally
- `"[^"]*"` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match from `"..."`
- `>` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `([_!=+])` Capture group 1, match any of the listed characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS51jt/1)

If there can be more than `name=` and no more occurrences of `<` and `>` you might also use:

```
<[^<>]*\bname="[^"]*"[^<>]*>|([_!=+])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8SyQY/1)

Answer (score 0):

Because variable length look behinds are not supported, you can't exclude matches that appear *after* particular text.

However, you can exclude a match immediately after `<name` and exclude matches within quotes, which is the best you can do given the limitations of regex:

```
(?<!<name)[_!=+](?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/0VRE2ncgMIdN5Y).